# Automatic mail generation using cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I couldn't understand this code so clearly as i'm new to cocoa. So can anyone please explain me this piece of code? Thanks in advance

```
NSString *emailString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\
                     tell application \"Mail\"\n\
                     set newMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:\"%@\", content:\"%@\" & return} \n\
                     tell newMessage\n\
                     set visible to false\n\
                     set sender to \"%@\"\n\
                     make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {name:\"%@\", address:\"%@\"}\n\
                     tell content\n\
                     ",subject, bodyText, @"McAlarm alert", @"McAlarm User", toAddress ];
```

Comment: Looks like AppleScript in an NSString.  Where the hell did you find this?

Answer (score 1):

This is an appleScript which is written in nsstring and later it will be executed to create a new mail with message, body etc.

If you want to send mail, you have another way to do so, not only by AS(apple script).

Few years back, it was considered as good way to accomplish some automation task. Now, even apple refuses to accept any application that use applescript.

So NEVER USE applescript for any purpose, in cocoa applications due to sandboxing.

EDIT:

```
- (void)sendEmailWithMail:(NSString *) senderAddress Address:(NSString *) toAddress Subject:(NSString *) subject Body:(NSString *) bodyText {
    NSString *mailtoAddress = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"mailto:%@?Subject=%@&body=%@",toAddress,subject,bodyText] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
    [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:mailtoAddress]];
}
```

Read this [Link](http://www.paullynch.org/blog/?p=61)

Comment: I have seen SBSendMail already, it requires configuring MAIL in Mac OS and it is not automatic. Instead of using applescript, is there any other way? Can you please help me out? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

SBSendMail is the best way to send email in cocoa

[SBSendMail](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SBSendEmail/Introduction/Intro.html)